# Convert characters such as Ã©, Ã‰, Ã¨, Ãª, ... to their regular UTF-8 form

Tags: sql, bash, utf-8

I made a dump of my MySQL tables, they are very old and I messed a lot with the charsets. The result is that, when I import this dump in a new database, I've got some kind of UTF8-to-ASCII characters everywhere (like the one in the title) in my tables and also in my resulting HTML pages.

I made a bash script to convert most of these characters: http://pastebin.com/fngz7qK2
But I'm not fond of this kind of brute forced conversion.

I'm not even trying to figure out what's wrong with my SQL tables, but I'd like to know if there is an easy, or standard, way to convert these weird characters into more regular one?

Answer (score 1):

If the source text file is indeed double-utf8-encoded (take utf8 characters as ISO-8859-1 character code numbers and encode them using the utf8 charecter code to byte sequence conversion algorithn), the conversion you do on the file is perfectly valid. Still, you probably should just reverse the extraneous iso-8859-1-to-utf8 conversion by running your text files through a utf8-to-iso8859-1-conversion, and treating the result as utf8. On linux, you might want to use `iconv -f utf8 -t latin1` instead of your ad-hoc conversion.

Comment: I didn't know the `iconv` command, very useful indeed! Now the problem is that the SQL dump is a mix of utf8 and latin1 characters, and thus your `iconv` command line also converts perfectly valid utf8 characters :/ Seems like I don't have much choice here...